# Table Grid addRows with Java API error in Jira

Tags: java, groovy, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

In Jira, I want to use addRows function with Java API in Scriptrunner, provided by Table Grid Next Generation plugin, but, I can't use beacuse of an error, which is not caused by syntaxis problem, since I take the example from the recomended code given by plugin. When I use the recommended code in documantation I get the error like this: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/jira/projectconfig/fields/ScreenFinder

And it continues hundreds of lines which is not understandable[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU2pu.jpg)